# Prefill on Vuejs input using js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to display the website on my app and prefill some values on the form of that website. How can I prefill on the Vuejs input using javascript.
I tried `document.getElementById('input-24').value = "Hello world"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Vuejs. You can give initial values in data function and bind them with input.

In component html

```
<input id="input-24" v-model="title">
```

Vue Js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data:function(){
       return {
            title:"Hello World"
       }
   }
});
```

as per your website. your Input need Focus First

document.getElementById('input-24').focus();
document.getElementById('input-24').value= "aaaaa";

But Focus does not work from Chrome console. The console gets ffocus after each command is run. so the focus will not work for the inputs from console.
but if you want to test this code from console you have to write in different manner as below.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('input-24').focus();
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('input-24').value = "Hello world"},2000);
 },5000);
```

After executing it immediately click anywhere on the page to take focus out of the console. now after 5 seconds the focus will set on the input..

But in script tag of the page it should be :

```
<script>

(function() {
   document.getElementById('input-24').focus();
   document.getElementById('input-24').value = "Hello world"
})();
</script>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: i am not a developer of that website. I can't access the source code. I just display it on my app using webview with prefill info like username, dob...

Comment: okay.  where are you adding this line. document.getElementById('input-24').value = "Hello world"

Comment: i am using elements on google chrome and run it on the console. 
here is website https://search.vaccine.gov.kh/

Comment: But this is working absolutely fine on your website. The only problem is overlapping of content with the Caption

Comment: no it not working, it won't get pass the validation when you click the button.

Comment: i have edited my answer for your website please check.